# Going to Sudan for work: will it cause problems getting a student visa?

Tags: visa, working-visas, pakistani-citizen

I am a technology Consultant, and I have to travel internationally for my job. I currently have to go to Sudan for the same reason. Will going to Sudan using a business visa cause a problem for me for my higher studies? I am planning to go to Europe or Canada for my masters; will a visa from Sudan on my passport cause a problem for me to get a visa in these countries? I am a Pakistani national.

Comment: https://travel.stackexchange.com/ would be a much better place to ask this question.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the countries of interest than "Europe"?